# Gradle multi project recursive task for dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, multi-project

Configuration:

I have multi project stricture like that

```
project1:
  implementation(1st_lvl_module1)
  implementation(1st_lvl_module2)
project2:
  implementation(1st_lvl_module1)
  implementation(1st_lvl_module2)
  implementation(1st_lvl_module3)
project3:
  implementation(1st_lvl_module2)

1st_lvl_module1:
  implementation(2nd_lvl_module1)
  implementation(2nd_lvl_module2)
1st_lvl_module2:
  implementation(2nd_lvl_module2)
1st_lvl_module3:
  implementation(2nd_lvl_module2)
  implementation(2nd_lvl_module3)

2nd_lvl_module1
2nd_lvl_module2
2nd_lvl_module3
```

---

Issue:

I want execute some task for all projects (eg. `gradle test`). It works as required for top level call. But I want to execute it for each project independently and here I have an issue.

If I do call for `gradle project1:test` it will be executed only for `project1` and does't include `1st_lvl_module1` which also implemented `2nd_lvl_module1 and 2nd_lvl_module2` and `1st_lvl_module2` with `2nd_lvl_module2`

---

- I tried to implement custom task
  E.g

```
tasks.register("testWithDependencies") { task ->
        task.dependsOn("test")
        configurations.forEach {
            it.dependencies.findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }.forEach {
                dependsOn ":${it.name}:test"
            }
        }
    }
```

And with this way it works as well for first level implimentations.
`gradle project1:testWithDependencies` will execute `test` task for `project1`, `1st_lvl_module1` and `1st_lvl_module2` but still ignore `2nd_lvl_module1  2nd_lvl_module2`.

- If I do execute for this task
  eg.

```
tasks.register("pd") { task ->
    configurations.forEach {
        println("Config name: ${it.name}")
        it.dependencies.findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }.forEach {
            def depProject = ((ProjectDependency)it).getDependencyProject()
            println("${depProject.name}")
            depProject.configurations.forEach {
                println("---Config name: ${it.name}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `project1` contains `implementation` configuration but all `1st_lvl_module*` doesn't. Actually `configurations` list for submodules looks very poor.

---

Question:

Does someone have the same issue with multi module subproject structure? Or maybe easiest way for recursive call is exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:
File eg. `testWithDependency.gradle` with follow content:

```
tasks.register("testWithDependencies") { task ->
        task.dependsOn("test")
        configurations.forEach {
            it.dependencies.findAll { it instanceof ProjectDependency }.forEach {
                dependsOn ":${it.name}:testWithDependencies"
            }
        }
    }
```

Should be applied **in the end** *(when dependencies of project will be validated)* of `gradle.build` for each project and module.

This solution also can be scalable for multiple tasks.